# Is there a way to update Primefaces form without losing data in it?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have form inside dialog and I need to update it when user click button. Button is for showing new fields in this form. Fields are not rendered by default in dialog(`render="#{gettForBoolean}"`).

When I am trying to use `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(formID);` in backing bean and always all data are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Normal input is not saving to variable when writing, but it can be done by ajax: `<p:ajax event="keyup" process="@widgetVar(inputID)"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The *process*  attribute avoid you loosing data in AJAX calls:

```
<p:ajax update="formId" actionListener="#{bean.method}" />
```

Comment: `process="@form"` is the default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: `<p:commandXxx process>` defaults to `@form` while `<p:ajax process>` and `<f:ajax execute>` defaults to `@this`